# Get OpenSSL FIPS Module Version Number

Tags: openssl

Is there a way for a user to determine *what version* of the FIPS module was compiled into OpenSSL? When I say "as user", I mean is there some functionality buried in the command line interface to get this information.

I know that I can tell that the FIPS module was built-in using the following:

```
# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1g-fips 7 April 2014
```

But what I really want to know is the value of `FIPS_MODULE_VERSION_TEXT`, which, in my case, would be 2.0.6.

Comment: Wondering if you were able to find an answer to your question.. update?

Comment: No, I haven't found an answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a c program and link with the fips validated library. Call FIPS_module_version_text() from this program and you will get the module version.

Comment: Hello ShardGupta. Are you sure this would link with the same library as used by the compiled version of the OpenSSL utility?

Comment: True, a program could be built to do that. But what I'm looking for is something available that is already there to examine or run. In the situation I have, the person testing the version number is a regular user, does not have a compiler and cannot write code.